# API request returning status code 404 not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Im making a fantasy stock app. when making a valid request to the API, the data gets returned as expected. If a stock does not exist, the server returns "Request failed with status code 404". I am trying to handle the error by logging the status to the console but the app does not catch the 404 error and the request stays pending. I cant find a way to handle the error so that it exits the promise to show the user that the stock is invalid.

my backend is as follows

```
app.get('/api/stocks', (req, res) => {
    const stockName = req.query.stockName
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${stockName}/quote?token=${testSecretKey}`
    })
        .then(response => {
            res.json(response.data);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message)
    })
})
```

my front end

```
    handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.searchTerm !== '') {
            await axios.get("api/stocks", {
                params: {
                    stockName: this.state.searchTerm
                }
            })
                .then((res, req) => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        this.setState({ stock: res.data, searchTerm: '', isStockValid: true });
                        console.log(res.status);
                    } else {
                        console.log(res.status)
                    }
                })
                // .catch(() => { console.log('error 404') });
            
            } else {
                alert('Enter a stock symbol. Example: AAPL for Apple inc.');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to return the error. Currently you're just console.logging the error and then nothing else, thats why it just stays pending.

```
app.get('/api/stocks', (req, res) => {
    const stockName = req.query.stockName
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${stockName}/quote?token=${testSecretKey}`
    })
        .then(response => {
            res.json(response.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.send(err);
    })
})
```